# Is it possible to handle image and video files without saving them in Python?

Tags: python, image, audio, video, mp4

I'm currently working in Python on a project that utilizes several libraries to manipulate audio, video, and image files. My first version saved all of the files (.mp3, .mp4, .jpg) using one library just to re-opened them in the others. When my program completed, I was left with hundreds of saved files that I would have to manually delete.

Is there any way to save files as variables and just manipulate them within Python (Lets say in a list)? If not, is there an easier way to save these into a temporary file?

Comment: Yes, you can store them as bytes using `BytesIO`. Perhaps, you should take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: Can you post the code snippet to show where you are saving it ?If you are "saving" the files that must mean that the data was already in some variable? Also alternatively you could just create a python script to delete the *.mp3/ *.mp4 files.

Comment: What you are saying is what I initially thought to try: just putting what I was saving into variables. I ran into issues when I wanted to use library specific functions on them. For instance, a PIL image doesn't have the same capabilities as a moviepy image and vise versa.

Comment: Working with video in memory is challenging. Most of the libraries expects real file, and don't support BytesIO. There are Python packages like [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) that support temporary files and folders. Try storing the files in a temporary folder.